# When I use JSDoc with "Namespace" and "Module" in a project, listed classes and Namespace documentation disappeared from module html page

Tags: jsdoc

I am documenting a project with JSDoc and Docstrap.

When the documentation is organized to(2) JS files (or modules), the generated documentation is OK. Each module lists two(classes).

Next, I included included in addition to "modules, the "namespace" a But, now the listed classes per module in html page disappeared.

**QUESTION:**
How to make JSDoc to continue including the classes list inside the module html page.

#### Input code before including "namespace"

JS files: "ModuleFile01.js", "ModuleFile02.js"

**ModuleFile01.js**

```
/** 
 * @module Part1/Section01
 * @description Section 01 of Part1
 */

/**
 * Class 1.01
 */
class Part1Class1 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}

/**
 * Class 1.02
 */
class Part1Class2 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}
```

**ModuleFile02.js**

```
/** 
 * @module Part1/Section02
 * @description Section 02 of Part1
 */

/**
 * Class 1.02
 */
class Part1Class3 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}

/**
 * Class 1.02
 */
class Part1Class4 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
```

#### JSDoc configuration

```js
{
    "recurseDepth": 10,
    "source": {
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc|x)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_|.+\\.min.js"
    },
    "sourceType": "module",
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags": true,
        "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
    },
    "plugins": 
        [   "plugins/markdown"
        ],
    "templates": {
        "outputSourceFiles": true,
        "outputSourcePath": false,
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "dateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM",
        "systemName": "Test project",
        "footer": "",
        "copyright": "DocStrap Copyright © 2012-2015 The contributors to the JSDoc3 and DocStrap projects.",
        "navType": "vertical",
        "theme": "readable",
        "linenums": true,
        "collapseSymbols": false,
        "inverseNav": true,
        "protocol": "html://",
        "methodHeadingReturns": false
    },
    "markdown": {
        "parser": "gfm",
        "hardwrap": true
    }
}
```

#### JSDoc debug output before including "namespace"

```
DEBUG: JSDoc 3.5.5 (Thu, 14 Sep 2017 02:51:54 GMT)
DEBUG: Environment info: {"env":{"conf":{"plugins":["plugins/markdown"],"recurseDepth":10,"source":{"includePattern":".+\\.js(doc|x)?$","excludePattern":"(^|\\/|\\\\)_|.+\\.min.js"},"sourceType":"module","tags":{"allowUnknownTags":true,"dictionaries":["jsdoc","closure"]},"templates":{"monospaceLinks":false,"cleverLinks":false,"outputSourceFiles":true,"outputSourcePath":false,"dateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM","systemName":"Test project","footer":"","copyright":"DocStrap Copyright © 2012-2015 The contributors to the JSDoc3 and DocStrap projects.","navType":"vertical","theme":"readable","linenums":true,"collapseSymbols":false,"inverseNav":true,"protocol":"html://","methodHeadingReturns":false},"markdown":{"parser":"gfm","hardwrap":true}},"opts":{"_":["src"],"configure":"JSDoc.cfg.json","template":"C:/Users/cpass/node_modules/ink-docstrap/template","destination":"doc","recurse":true,"verbose":true,"debug":true,"encoding":"utf8"}}}
DEBUG: Parsing source files: ["D:\\JavaProjects\\JavaScript\\LWPS\\docs\\test01\\src\\ModuleFile01.js","D:\\JavaProjects\\JavaScript\\LWPS\\docs\\test01\\src\\ModuleFile02.js"]
Parsing D:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS\docs\test01\src\ModuleFile01.js ...
Parsing D:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS\docs\test01\src\ModuleFile02.js ...
DEBUG: Finished parsing source files.
DEBUG: Indexing doclets...
DEBUG: Adding inherited symbols, mixins, and interface implementations...
DEBUG: Adding borrowed doclets...
DEBUG: Post-processing complete.
Generating output files...
Finished running in 0.48 seconds.
```

#### Input code after including "namespace"

JS files: "Cat-Classes", "ModuleFile01.js", "ModuleFile02.js"

**Cat-Classes.js** (Only documentation, no code)

```
/** 
 * @namespace sections
 * @description Section 01 and 02 of Part1
 * The html page for this namespace lists all classes from "Module01.js" and "Module01.js".
 */
```

**ModuleFile01.js**

```
/** 
 * @module Part1/Section01
 * @description Section 01 of Part1
 */

/**
 * Class 1.01
 * @memberof sections
 */
class Part1Class1 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}

/**
 * Class 1.02
 * @memberof sections
 */
class Part1Class2 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}
```

**ModuleFile02.js**

```
/** 
 * @module Part1/Section02
 * @description Section 02 of Part1
 */

/**
 * Class 1.02
 * @memberof sections
 */
class Part1Class3 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}

/**
 * Class 1.02
 * @memberof sections
 */
class Part1Class4 {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor() {}
}
```

#### JSDoc debug output after including "namespace" : "sections"

```
DEBUG: JSDoc 3.5.5 (Thu, 14 Sep 2017 02:51:54 GMT)
DEBUG: Environment info: {"env":{"conf":{"plugins":["plugins/markdown"],"recurseDepth":10,"source":{"includePattern":".+\\.js(doc|x)?$","excludePattern":"(^|\\/|\\\\)_|.+\\.min.js"},"sourceType":"module","tags":{"allowUnknownTags":true,"dictionaries":["jsdoc","closure"]},"templates":{"monospaceLinks":false,"cleverLinks":false,"outputSourceFiles":true,"outputSourcePath":false,"dateFormat":"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM","systemName":"Test project","footer":"","copyright":"DocStrap Copyright © 2012-2015 The contributors to the JSDoc3 and DocStrap projects.","navType":"vertical","theme":"readable","linenums":true,"collapseSymbols":false,"inverseNav":true,"protocol":"html://","methodHeadingReturns":false},"markdown":{"parser":"gfm","hardwrap":true}},"opts":{"_":["src"],"configure":"JSDoc.cfg.json","template":"C:/Users/cpass/node_modules/ink-docstrap/template","destination":"doc","recurse":true,"verbose":true,"debug":true,"encoding":"utf8"}}}
DEBUG: Parsing source files: ["D:\\JavaProjects\\JavaScript\\LWPS\\docs\\test02\\src\\Cat-Classes.js","D:\\JavaProjects\\JavaScript\\LWPS\\docs\\test02\\src\\ModuleFile01.js","D:\\JavaProjects\\JavaScript\\LWPS\\docs\\test02\\src\\ModuleFile02.js"]
Parsing D:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS\docs\test02\src\Cat-Classes.js ...
Parsing D:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS\docs\test02\src\ModuleFile01.js ...
Parsing D:\JavaProjects\JavaScript\LWPS\docs\test02\src\ModuleFile02.js ...
DEBUG: Finished parsing source files.
DEBUG: Indexing doclets...
DEBUG: Adding inherited symbols, mixins, and interface implementations...
DEBUG: Adding borrowed doclets...
DEBUG: Post-processing complete.
Generating output files...
Finished running in 0.51 seconds.
```

I am documenting a project with JSDoc and Docstrap.

The created projec includes two(2) JS files (or modules), and two(2) classes per JS file.
Each module web page lists the classes inside the module.

I successfully created a documentation with modules, and a "namespace" which is listing all classes from the files ModuleFile01.js and ModuleFile02.js

I just created a JS file without code, only documentation.

Now, the documentation includes a "namespace" listing all project classes.
But, now the listed classes per module in html page disappeared.

**QUESTION:**
How to make JSDoc to continue including the classes list inside the module html page.

#### My environment

| Software         | Version |
| :--------------- | :------ |
| JSDoc            | JSDoc 3.5.5 (Thu, 14 Sep 2017 02:51:54 GMT) |
| Node.js          | v10.15.0 |
| npm              | 6.4.1 |
| Operating system | Windows 10 Pro, 64 bits, Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.503) |

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to replace `* @memberof sections` with

```js
* @memberof module:Part1/Section01
```

and don't declare `* @namespace sections`. Modules are an alternative to namespace requiring the `module:...` prefix.

I battled with the same problem until reading the *Special cases: modules, externals and events* section of the [namepath](https://jsdoc.app/about-namepaths) documentation.